# VMWare Thousands of logs VFC: VFC_TreePrepPage:1170: Can not insert key into policy Busy

Tags: vmware, vmware-server

Today I saw thousands of log like "VFC: VFC_TreePrepPage:1170: Can not insert key into policy Busy" into file vmkernel.log. I searched on the internet but could not find the issue. Anybody helps me to find this issue.
Thank a lot.

[image]

Comment: Did you activate Virtual Flash Read Cache (vFRC) recently? Here ( http://communities927.rssing.com/chan-9411850/all_p2642.html ) they got same warning, but in 2015 vmware support had nothing published about it.

Comment: Yes. I activated Virtual Flash Read Cache. I added a SDD disk want to improve performance. I have many servers activated vFRC. But just only that server have that log. I could not know why. Can U give me some suggest?

Comment: Finally. I found my SDD Disk have problem with Virtual Flash Read Cache. I  remove Virtual Flash Read Cache. Format SSD Disk again. Then these errors disappear.